# While taking database backup Odoo11 causes Error

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-11

While taking backup from odoo11, gives error. How to solve this?

> Database backup error: Postgres subprocess ('/usr/bin/pg_dump', '--no-owner', '--file=/tmp/tmpa36uaqdp/dump.sql', 'simple_25_10_19') error 1

Comment: This error is not really helpful, try to look into the log files and find the real error message. Most of my experienced problems with Odoo and postgres are different postgres server and client versions: For example Odoo uses postgres client 10.0 but the postgres server uses 11.0.

Comment: '--no-owner', Did you check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when your PostgreSQL client and server versions do not match. Check your versions.

More info for Postgres versions in the docker setup can be found here [odoo12 database backup no owner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989761/odoo12-database-backup-no-owner/53993856#53993856).

Answer (score -1):

I had Odoo 12CE on Amazon AWS. The problem is the HDD was full.

[[image: screenshots]]
Enjoy!!

```
      2020-05-24 14:21:44,230 1280 INFO xxxxx.mx odoo.service.db: DUMP DB: xxxx.mx format zip

      2020-05-24 14:23:22,250 1280 ERROR xxxx.mx odoo.addons.web.controllers.main:Database.backup

      Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/opt/odoosrc/12.0/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 758, in backup
    dump_stream = odoo.service.db.dump_db(name, None, backup_format)

    File "<decorator-gen-9>", line 2, in dump_db
      File "/opt/odoosrc/12.0/odoo/odoo/service/db.py", line 40, in if_db_mgt_enabled
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)

    File "/opt/odoosrc/12.0/odoo/odoo/service/db.py", line 225, in dump_db
    odoo.tools.exec_pg_command(*cmd)

    File "/opt/odoosrc/12.0/odoo/odoo/tools/misc.py", line 129, in exec_pg_command
    raise Exception('Postgres subprocess %s error %s' % (args2, rc))

    Exception: Postgres subprocess ('/usr/bin/pg_dump', '--no-owner', '--file=/tmp/tmppiurb5iy/dump.sql', 'solidaridad.dri.com.mx') error 1
```