# Database backup error: Postgres subprocess ....--no-owner', '--file=C:\\windows\\TEMP\\tmpf9zumbp9\\dump.sql', 'CP3') error 1

Tags: postgresql, windows, odoo, pg-dump

A have odoo 15 installed on Windows server 2016; everything is working very well but;

When i try to backup the database i get this error:

> Database backup error: Postgres subprocess ('C:\Odoo15\PostgreSQL\bin\pg_dump.exe', '--no-owner', '--file=C:\windows\TEMP\tmpf9zumbp9\dump.sql', 'CP3') error 1

When i try pg_dump:

```
C:\Odoo15\PostgreSQL\bin>pg_dump -U postgres -W -Fc -d "test" >C:\Odoo15\PostgreSQL\cp3.dump
```

> pg_dump: erreur : connection to database 'test' failed: connection to server was terminated unexpectedly The server may have terminated abnormally before or during the request processing.

1. Give all rights on the database to pgadmin and set it as a owner
2. Apply following tutos :

- https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/database-backup-error-postgres-subprocess-usr-bin-pg-dump-no-owner-file-tmp-tmpaa0o5q-dump-sql-u-ahlain-db01-error-1-118245
  -https://github.com/odoo/docker/issues/234
- [While taking database backup Odoo11 causes Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557794/while-taking-database-backup-odoo11-causes-error)

Comment: What does the PostgreSQL log tell you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [psql: server closed the connection unexepectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934364/psql-server-closed-the-connection-unexepectedly)

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Owner` of the database that you want to take the backup. And run the odoo as that user and take the back up.
For example, owner of the DB is: odoo15
run the  odoo as odoo15 (in ubuntu `sudo su - odoo15 -s /bin/bash`) then run your odoo server and you can take the backup from the Database manager window.